# What happens if I give same state to a react component

Tags: reactjs

I have a react component, whose state gets changed from lots of places and I don't have sufficient checks in place to control whether setState should get called or not. That means a lot of times setState gets called and updates a key in a state with the same value (value that key already had before).

My assumption is if value of myPreviousState and value of myNewState remains same no rerender will happen. Is it true?

If it is not true, can you tell me what is the best way to deep compare my previous state with new state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate)** to avoid un-necessary rendering

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {

  // check here whether u want to update your component or not using nextProps or
  // nextState

  if (this.state.myValue !== nextState.myValue) {

      return true; //update component

  } else {

      return false //dont update
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Riyaz, does this gets called after componentWillReceiveProps? And does this.state.myValue !== nextState.myValue do a deep comparison of object?

Comment: yes,after `componentWillReceiveProps` this will get called.For deep comparision you have write your own script

Answer (score 1):

If your state is changed by many component then you should use a state management library like `redux/mobx` and components will listen and if required change that variable.
Redux(since it is the most popular) will take care of your view update.

Believe me, it will be really messy when you keep doing setState for shared state.

Comment: I know about Redux, but at this point of time I am not interested in lots of refactoring.

Answer (score 1):

You should be used **shouldComponentUpdate** where you can easily differentiate nextState and currentState.

You can avoid calling render function when these two states will be same.

You can go to the following link:-

https://developmentarc.gitbooks.io/react-indepth/content/life_cycle/update/using_should_component_update.html

But Performance-based you must use state management library like redux. You can control your state objects.